# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on pylucene initVM()

Tags: python, ubuntu, lucene, pylucene

I use pylucene to build a lucene search with python.
I think after some system updates on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS workstation today I get an error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" on every call of lucene.initVM(). Lucene is the default ubuntu package installed by apt-get install.

I get the error on python commandline and also on usage in my script.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lucene
>>> lucene.initVM()
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben) -> in english something like segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can you give me an advice how I can correct this issue?